# looping through checkboxes and inserting checkbox values to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**ASPX Page:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvSubjects" runat="server" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRegularSubjects" Text=<%# Eval("SubjectName") %> runat="server" />

        </ItemTemplate>


        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRegularSubjects" Text=<%# Eval("SubjectName") %> runat="server" />
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Page.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox AndAlso CType(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked Then
                '**Here I want to get the text of the check box and insert into the DB**
            End If


       Next
```

Where am i going wrong??i do not get any error...but this code is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lvSubjects.Items.Count - 1
            Dim coll As ControlCollection = lvSubjects.Items(i).Controls
            For Each c As Control In coll
                If TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then
                    Dim box As CheckBox = CType(c, CheckBox)
                    If box.Checked Then
                        MsgBox(box.Text)
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

you are only searching in Page.Controls whereas your checkboxes are inside deeper in page control hierarichy.

```
foreach (ListViewItem row in listView.Rows)
{
  if (row.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
  {
    CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("Checkboxid");
    if  (chk.Checked)
    {
     //Write code to store this checkbox value to database here
    }
   }
  }
```

Please change the code in VB with proper control name

Comment: The list view is inside a panel and the checkboxes are inside the listview ...i want to execute the code on a button click...how do i go about it??

Comment: and i am also using a master page.

Comment: i get `ItemRow` is not defined.

Comment: `Row` is not a member of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView`